# Javascript Generated HTML Buttons with onClick Custom Function

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page that has javascript, I'd like the javascript to generate HTML buttons like this:

```
<button class="btnFormat" onclick="var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '#xxxxx';
        link.click(); window.location.reload() "> AYOU1 </button>
<button class="btnFormat" onclick="var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '#xxxxx';
        link.click(); window.location.reload() "> AYOU1 </button>
<button class="btnFormat" onclick="var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '#xxxxx';
        link.click(); window.location.reload() "> AYOU1 </button>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the javascript to add the class or onClick 'strings'.  My code runs without errors but looking at the output it is just:

```
<button>AYOU1</button>
<button>AYOU2</button>
<button>AYOU3</button>
```

This is the code that I have been working on (it doesn't have the class=, as I can't figure out the onClick= part...):

```
  <html>

    <body>

<script>
    var items = [
      {hex: "OBFPUOX6T",            alpha: "AYOU1"          },
      {hex: "LC7THLODH",            alpha: "AYOU2"          },
      {hex: "RNPODALAJ",            alpha: "AYOU3"          },
      {hex: "2FSCQ4LGK",            alpha: "AYOU4"          },
    ]

    var i = 0;
    const parentElement = document.querySelector('body'); // DOM location when buttons will be added

    items.forEach(function(item) {
      const pButton = document.createElement("button");
      pButton.innerText = item.alpha;
      pButton.onClick = function() {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '#' + item.hex;
        window.location.reload();
      };
      i++;
      console.log(pButton, i)
      parentElement.appendChild(pButton); // to add new element to DOM
    })

</script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I would appreciate any help!  Thank you in advance!

I added the full source code here: https://jsfiddle.net/kilimar/7eL15azm/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can add `pButton.classList.add('btnFormat');` right after you define the `const pButton` to add the class in the markup. Now, for the important part - why do you want to add all of that information in the button's markup for `onclick` rather than call a function that handles all of that?

Comment: I just found that I can replace the class with something like 'pButton.className = ("btnFormat");`  So either will work for me since it's the only style being applied.   Sorry, but I'm not very good and I'm just clobbering code together.  If you have a better way, I'm all ears!

Comment: This also doesn't work:

```
function test () {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#'+ item.hex;
    window.location.reload();
};

var items = [
    {hex: "OBFPUOX6T"  , alpha:  "AYOU1"},
    {hex: "LC7THLODH"  , alpha:  "AYOU2"},
]

const parentElement = document.querySelector('body'); 
items.forEach(function(item) {
  const pButton = document.createElement("button");
  pButton.innerText = item.alpha;
  pButton.className = ("btnFormat");
  pButton.onClick = test;
   
  parentElement.appendChild(pButton); 
})


```

Comment: Let's start from the beginning: what are you actually trying to accomplish with those buttons? I'm not talking code, but what do you want them to do? This seems like an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I would like the button to reload the page with a bookmark.  There is code on the page that parses the URL (which now includes the bookmark after you press the button) and pulls out the bookmark and uses it to generate data.

The current code has the buttons with the onClick with the bookmarks.  I would like to convert that section of the code into javascript so that rather than cut & paste <button>, I can just add an item in the array.  Does that help?  If not I can post the original script in paste.bin or something.

Comment: Let's see what you currently have. Edit the question to add that code.

Comment: I've added a link to jsfiddle which has the full code.

Comment: @kilimar your code looks fine. `onclick` is an attribute of a `<button>`. It will not show up in the DOM like you expect. However, you can see the event listeners for the button in your browser's devtools.

Comment: Yet, when I click the JavaScript generated buttons, nothing happens as compared to the manually added buttons which refreshes the page and the code shows up.  So I'm fairly confused.  I mean the code looks like it should work but the rendered code doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If your output doesn't show any classes, it's because all of the events are handled in the background, it is also probably a good practice to do it that way.

Though, your script have some errors and can be simplified:

1. `pButton.onclick` is lowercase (not `pButton.onClick`)

   ```js
   pButton.onclick = function() { // [...]
   ```
2. Then there's a very useful property: `location.hash` (also `window` is not necessary)

   ```js
   location.hash = '#' + item.hex;
   location.reload();
   ```
3. (Bonus!) there's a shortcut for `document.querySelector('body')`

   ```js
   const parentElement = document.body
   ```

Anyways, here's the whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var items = [
        {hex: "OBFPUOX6T", alpha: "AYOU1"},
        {hex: "LC7THLODH", alpha: "AYOU2"},
        {hex: "RNPODALAJ", alpha: "AYOU3"},
        {hex: "2FSCQ4LGK", alpha: "AYOU4"},
      ]

      var i = 0;
      const parentElement = document.body; // DOM location when buttons will be added

      items.forEach(function(item) {
        const pButton = document.createElement("button");
        pButton.innerText = item.alpha;
        pButton.onclick = function() {
          location.hash = '#' + item.hex;
          location.reload();
        };
        i++;
        console.log(pButton, i)
        parentElement.appendChild(pButton); // to add new element to DOM
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helped !

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your solution worked.

Comment: @kilimar Happy to hear it !